# Creating a single controller to return both data and views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've been playing around with `ASP.NET MVC 4 beta` and I noticed two controllers: one(web api controller) to return data and the other(default controller) to return views.

I'm aware that even `HTML` is a type of representation for a resource like `JSON` or `XML` and I'm not personally so happy having a separate controller to return only `HTML` representation.

What I'm trying to achieve is having a single controller that will return both views and data. But I'm confused is this a best option and if it is how can I achieve this without much code.

Can I extend the `ApiController` such that it will return both views as well as data or can I create a generic controller that by passes the requests  to particular controller type based upon the `"accept-type"`.

I'm looking for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a formatter rendering your HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do u have any ideas how to use razor view engine inside the custom html formatter?

Comment: I think you'll have to run your own razor engine instace like this: http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=208

Answer (score 1):

The official [Contact Manager example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Contact-Manager-Web-API-0e8e373d/sourcecode?fileId=49595&pathId=703556504) describes how to use formatters to render in any of the following html/json/png/vcf within a single controller.

You'll have to add the valid routes, if you want to explicitly request within the url.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
            "Default", // Route name 
            "{controller}/{id}/{ext}", // URL with parameters 
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, ext = RouteParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults 
        );
```

But if you are actually setting the "accept-type" header, that should pretty much work out of the box